# React key on grouped list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error that I need to have a unique key prop for each child in a list. However I'm adding `li` elements to a `ul` in groups based on the dates supplied. So I don't have a parent element to attach a `key` prop to. As you can see from the code below I've attempted to add it to each `li` element inside the fragment but it's not good enough for react apparently.

Any suggestions?

```js
export const DeskBookCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ desk, dates, bookAction }: Props) =>{

return <section className={styles['desk-book-card']}>
  <h2>{desk.name}</h2>
  <form onSubmit={() => bookAction()}>
  <ul className={styles['checkbox-list']}>
    {
      dates.map(date => {
        const DATE_FORMAT = 'EEEE, do LLLL'
        return <>
          <li key={`${format(date, 'T')}-am`}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name={`${format(date, 'T')}-am`} id={`${date}-am`}/>
              {format(date, DATE_FORMAT)} - AM
            </label>
          </li>
          <li key={`${format(date, 'T')}-pm`}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name={`${format(date, 'T')}-pm`} id={`${date}-pm`}/>
              {format(date, DATE_FORMAT)} - PM
            </label>
          </li>
        </>
      })
    }
    
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Book a desk</button>
  <button>cancel</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to add the key to the `<>` wrapper. For that your can use React.Fragment

Answer (score 2):

I switched to using the longform `React.Fragment` instead of the `<>` shorthand and I was able to apply a `key` prop to that:

e.g. `<React.Fragment key={format(date, 'T')}>`